# How to add html tags inside double quotes

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

I have a script like below,

```
var content = "<p>Please click on the text below.<br><a "href="www.testifyme.com">More Info</a></p>"
```

Html,

```
<span [innerHtml]="content"></span>
```

Here the problem is with my anchor tag,how to add href value in double quotes since the `"<a href:"www.....>`

Here I am getting error at href.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: try : `var content = '<p>Please click on the text below.<br><a href="www.testifyme.com">More Info</a></p>'`

Comment: You can also use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), like so `\`<p>Please click on the text below.<br><a href="www.testifyme.com">More Info</a></p>\``

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the `"` like so: `\"` or you can use single quotes `'` *within* the double ones for `a href` or `classes`

Answer (score 0):

When i have just entered the job, I usually put them in single quotes or concat strings

```
var content = '<p>Please click on the text below.<br><a href="www.testifyme.com">More Info</a></p>'
```

I have known to use slash, later

```
var content =  "<p>Please click on the text below.<br><a href=\"www.testifyme.com\">More Info</a></p>"
```

When i have known ES6, i use ```

```
var content = `<p>Please click on the text below.<br><a href="www.testifyme.com">More Info</a></p>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your javascript variable.

You have two bugs.
The first one is the double quotes before `href` those are not needed.

The other problem is the quotes for the actual link, that is causing a syntax error, since javascript thinks you are closing the string variable.

You have several options to fix that.

Use single quotes for the string variable:

```
var content = '<p>Please click on the text below.<br><a href="www.testifyme.com">More Info</a></p>';
```

Note the first and last quotes are single quotes.

Or to escape the double quotes using the escape character `\`

```
var content = "<p>Please click on the text below.<br><a href=\"www.testifyme.com\">More Info</a></p>";
```

A third option (I would not personally recommended it for this specific case, but I included it for reference) could be to use template literals with the `` ` `` character:

```
var content = `<p>Please click on the text below.<br><a href="www.testifyme.com">More Info</a></p>`;
```

Not the first and last are backticks `` ` ``

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals